# Javascript & HTML: How can I display the time to appear in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How I can display may full date in HTML?

Below, I have a basic function that displays the time which looks something like this: xxxx-x-x xx:xx:x

Also, my current output is console.log, but I'm wondering how you would do it to get some ideas.

```
function time() {
    var date = new Date();
    var str = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) 
+ '-' + date.getDate() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    return str;
}

console.log(time());
```

Comment: Assign the string to `innerText` of the DOM element you want it to display in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString()` for that

```
function time() {
    var date = new Date();
    return date.toLocaleString();
}

console.log(time());

const dateText = document.createElement('span');
span.innerText = time();
document.appendChild(span);

// or
document.write(time());
```

Comment: The question is how to display it in his web page rather than the console.

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js for this.:
[check sample code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TAaj.png)

> let myDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',new Date());

further reads:
https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
setInterval(() => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<p>'+time()+'</p>';
}, 1000);
```

You can change "document.body.innerHTML" as you wanted.
eg "document.getElementById("time").innerHTML"